# Apply Folder Icon Change

Tags: c#, windows, icons, file-attributes, desktop.ini

I am attempting to change the icon of a folder. The code below does all what I found online says to do but the icon never changes. Am I maybe not "Applying" the change?

```
string createdFile = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\np\Desktop\PUTEST", "desktop.ini");
if (File.Exists(createdFile))
{
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(createdFile);
    di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

    File.Delete(createdFile);
    File.Create(createdFile).Dispose();
}
else
{
    File.Create(createdFile).Dispose();
}


//string iconPath = @"%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll";
string iconPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll");
string iconIndex = "-183";
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(createdFile))
{
    tw.WriteLine("[.ShellClassInfo]");
    tw.WriteLine("IconResource=" + iconPath + "," + iconIndex);
    //tw.WriteLine("IconFile=" + iconPath);
    //tw.WriteLine("IconIndex=" + iconIndex);

}


File.SetAttributes(createdFile, System.IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
File.SetAttributes(createdFile, System.IO.FileAttributes.System);
File.SetAttributes(createdFile, System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When crafting a file like this it's always good to do so using Explorer or Notepad first, then write/adjust your code to match whatever was produced.  Otherwise, it's harder to figure out if the problem is with your file or your code.

I believe the minimum requirements to make this work is `Desktop.ini` must be marked `System` and the parent directory must be marked `ReadOnly` (`System` may work there as well, but I know `ReadOnly` definitely does).  So, your code is working with the right attributes, but there are still a few problems.

Your `if ... else ...` block is saying "If a file exists at this path, create a directory at that path, then delete the file at that path, then create a file at that path."  Of course, the directory should not and cannot have the same path as the file.  I assume you are deleting and recreating the file to clear the contents when it already exists, however `File.Create()` overwrites (truncates) existing files, making the calls to both `File.Delete()` and `File.Exists()` unnecessary.

More importantly is this line...

```
di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

...with which there are two problems.  First, you are ANDing the directory's attributes with the negation of `ReadOnly`, which has the effect of removing `ReadOnly` and keeping the other attributes the same.  You want to ensure `ReadOnly` is *set* on the directory, so you want to do the opposite of the code you used: OR the directory's attributes with `ReadOnly` (not negated)...

```
di.Attributes |= FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

Also, you need that attribute set regardless of whether you created the directory or not, so that line should be moved outside of the `if ... else ...`.

Another issue is the successive calls to `File.SetAttributes()`.  After those three calls the file's attributes will be only `Hidden`, since that was the value of the last call.  Instead, you need to combine (bitwise OR) those attributes in a single call.

A couple of other minor tweaks...

- As you know since you are calling `Dispose()` on it, `File.Create()` returns a `FileStream` to that file.  Instead of throwing it away, you could use it to create your `StreamWriter`, which will have to create one, anyways, under the covers.  Better yet, call `File.CreateText()` instead and it will create the `StreamWriter` for you.
- Environment variables are supported in `Desktop.ini` files, so you don't have to expand them yourself.  This would make the file portable between systems if, say, you copied it from one system to another, or the directory is on a network share accessed by multiple systems with different `%SystemRoot%` values.

Incorporating all of the above changes your code becomes...

```
// Create a new directory, or get the existing one if it exists
DirectoryInfo directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\np\Desktop\PUTEST");
directory.Attributes |= FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

string filePath = Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "desktop.ini");
string iconPath = @"%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll";
string iconIndex = "-183";

using (TextWriter tw = File.CreateText(filePath))
{
    tw.WriteLine("[.ShellClassInfo]");
    tw.WriteLine("IconResource=" + iconPath + "," + iconIndex);
    //tw.WriteLine("IconFile=" + iconPath);
    //tw.WriteLine("IconIndex=" + iconIndex);
}

File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.ReadOnly | FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

One catch is that the above code throws an exception if you run it twice in succession.  This is because the `File.Create*()` methods fail if the input file is `Hidden` or `ReadOnly`.  We could use `new FileStream()` as an alternative, but that still throws an exception if the file is `ReadOnly`.  Instead, we'll just have to remove those attributes from any existing input file before opening it...

```
// Create a new directory, or get the existing one if it exists
DirectoryInfo directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\np\Desktop\PUTEST");
directory.Attributes |= FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

string filePath = Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "desktop.ini");
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

try
{
    // Remove the Hidden and ReadOnly attributes so file.Create*() will succeed
    file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    // The file does not yet exist; no extra handling needed
}

string iconPath = @"%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll";
string iconIndex = "-183";

using (TextWriter tw = file.CreateText())
{
    tw.WriteLine("[.ShellClassInfo]");
    tw.WriteLine("IconResource=" + iconPath + "," + iconIndex);
    //tw.WriteLine("IconFile=" + iconPath);
    //tw.WriteLine("IconIndex=" + iconIndex);
}

file.Attributes = FileAttributes.ReadOnly | FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

I changed from using `File` to `FileInfo` since that makes this a little easier.

Comment: this works on a newly created folder but if the ini is present and you want to change the icon again I get an Accessed Denied on the ini

Comment: Yes, I am adding an edit to handle that situation right now.

Comment: I resolved this by removing the ini attributes upfront then their added later as your code reads. Thanks for the help!